Running test in parallel through NUnit.Engine
I have a UnitTest project (NUnit) to run my tests that accepts parameter thru TestContext.Parameters, I also have a runner that's handling the queuing of tests and I run it in parallel thru Task.Run(() => {}), it looks like it queues up properly and ran in parallel however it appears that the data I passed in going to my UnitTest Project (NUnit) looks like not properly being handled in the Test side as it only process the "last" data that I queued up
Here is my code from my runner
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testEventListener = new TestEventListener();

        var ids = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Queued: {0}", id);

                var filterBuilder = new TestFilterBuilder();

                filterBuilder.AddTest("TestProject1.Tests.Test1");

                var testFilter = filterBuilder.GetFilter();

                var testPackage = new TestPackage("TestProject1.dll");

                testPackage.AddSetting(FrameworkPackageSettings.TestParametersDictionary, new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "IDFromParameter", id }
                });

                var engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();

                var runner = engine.GetRunner(testPackage);

                runner.Run(testEventListener, testFilter);
            });
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

..and my UnitTest Project (NUnit) looks like this
namespace TestProject1
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(3, 5) * 1000);

            var id = TestContext.Parameters.Get("IDFromParameter");

            TestContext.WriteLine($"From TestProject1.Tests.Test1 ID: {id}");
        }
    }
}

In my console it shows up that it queues up 1,2 and 3 but my test only process the last entry

Do NUnit.Engine cannot process parallel run using this way?
Is there any other better way in doing this?
I prepared a running sample here https://github.com/vgdagpin/NUnitRunningParallel
EDIT: I downloaded the NUnit source and referenced it to my test project to try to debug it, when I run it it just works as expected, and I don't know why.


I'm not posting an answer but here are a few comments: (1) You are using the parameters package setting in an entirely different way from how NUnit uses it. A named parameter has only ONE value, in your case the last one you gave it. (2) You say you are "queuing" something and give a message, but no queuing is involved. NUnit internally queues tests for execution if you allow it to, but you are only running one test per execution of NUnit. (3) You are obviously trying to duplicate much of what NUnit already does. Is there a reason?

Thanks @Charlie, that's why i got the question "Is there any other better way in doing this?" because obviously I dont have any more idea how this work haha, I thought this package thing is what we send out to NUnit engine to run so feeding it as new instance inside Task.Run would do it
